# Python 3.5, trying to copy the content of one file into another by defining a function for it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't normally ask for help with assignments, but I was stumbled with a part question and I can't seem to get it right. The question is :

> Write a function fcopy() that takes as input two file names (as strings) and copies the
>   content of the first file into the second.

Now so far, this is what I've managed to come up with:

```
def fcopy(file1, file2):
os.chdir('C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/Introduction to Computing/Lab/assignments')
open_file_1 = open(file1, 'r')
open_file_2 = open(file2, 'w')
for line in open_file_1:
    open_file_2.write(line)
open_file_1.close()
open_file_2.close()
open_file_2 = open(file2, 'r')
for line in open_file_2:
    print(line)
open_file_2.close()
```

I managed to get so far by looking through many resources, and I want to know how to make this work. Thanks

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code so we know that it is an exact representation of your real code. Also, please explain what is currently not working out in your code. i.e. what unexpected behaviour is happening right now that leads you to believe things are not working out. Ultimately, you want to show the readers a good [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: well, first off, I don't know how to use the code, like what should i use in the fcopy() function, since it keeps giving me an error when i use the file name, and if there is anything wrong that I may have done in the coding.

Comment: code seems OK. Do you get error message or what ? always add full error message in question.

Comment: @TheJoker1911 you don't know how to use the code? Didn't you write the code?

Comment: @idjaw i used resources to help me write the code, and ive tested if it works outside of the def function, but in using the fcopy function, I don't know what to input to give me the same result as my test program

Comment: Did you try calling your function? `fcopy('your_first_file.txt', 'your_second_file.txt')`

Comment: I'll try doing that and I'll get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```
def fcopy(file1, file2):
    #os.chdir('C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/Introduction to Computing/Lab/assignments')
    open_file_1 = open(file1, 'r')
    open_file_2 = open(file2, 'w')
    for line in open_file_1:
        open_file_2.write(line)
    open_file_1.close()
    open_file_2.close()
    open_file_2 = open(file2, 'r')
    for line in open_file_2:
        print(line)
    open_file_2.close()
fcopy("infile.txt", "outfile.txt")
```

Here is another approach

```
def copy(infile, outfile):
    with open(infile) as file_input:
        with open(outfile, "w") as file_output:
            for line in file_input:
                file_output.write(line)
copy("infile.txt", "outfile.txt")
```

This approach is better because it guarantees you that outfile will be closed.

Printing content from infile and outfile

```
def fcopy(file1, file2):
    #os.chdir('C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/Introduction to Computing/Lab/assignments')
    open_file_1 = open(file1, 'r')
    open_file_2 = open(file2, 'w')
    print("-------------Infile-------------")
    for line in open_file_1:
        open_file_2.write(line)
        print(line)
    open_file_1.close()
    open_file_2.close()

    open_file_2 = open(file2, 'r')
    print()
    print("-------------Outfile-------------")
    for line in open_file_2:
        print(line)
    open_file_2.close()
fcopy("infile.txt", "outfile.txt")

def copy(infile, outfile):
    with open(infile) as file_input:
        with open(outfile, "w") as file_output:
            for line in file_input:
                file_output.write(line)
```

Second way

```
    with open(infile, "r") as file_in:
        print("Infile: ")
        for line2 in file_in:
            print(line2)

    print()

    with open(outfile, "r") as file_out:
        print("Outfile: ")
        for line3 in file_out:
            print(line3)            

copy("infile.txt", "outfile.txt")
```

I am sure there is more optimized way of doing this but this is the one I could do for now. I will update my answer if I find a better way to do this.

Comment: While your code is another approach to solve this problem, it isn't the reason why the OP is having trouble running their code. Also, if providing an alternative way to attack the problem, then explain why use this approach and how it helps.

Comment: this has helped make it work, thank you !!

Comment: You are welcome. Please let me know if you need help understanding any part of it.

Comment: @idjaw I will try to explain myself better in future solutions. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: one last question @Mani, I want to rename the code from copy() to fcopy(), while also printing the end results at the end. what do i need to change/add to make this work?

Comment: @TheJoker1911 by end result do you mean the outfile?

Comment: @mani, the infile before and after preferably, to show that the contents have been changed

Comment: @TheJoker1911 I have updated my answer. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: @mani first off, thank you very much for your help with this, I appreciate it

Comment: @Mani secondly, I wanted to ask what I need to change in order to use te function as fcopy() instead of only copy(), other than changing it in the def function, in order to remove any possible errors

Comment: one last problem @Mani, I ran the code multiple times with different text inside both files, and i noticed it copied the infile into the outfile, when its supposed to be the other way around, any solutions?

Comment: Just change the files , change in infile to outfile and vice versa (in the code)